# Audio Analyser bar graphics in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I've found a tutorial to make an Audio Analyser bar graphics in HTML5 [here](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1348). 
I'm trying to make it in iOS and I've a question.

To get the frequency-domain data it use :

```
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
```

What the equivalent of this function in iOS ?

Comment: There is no one-to-one equivalent. Many people use the accelerate framework's FFT functions, but for this you must understand how the FFT works.